# String.Format, single trailign space only for positives

Tags: c#, string, format, decimal

I'm trying to use string.format to apply the format {0:#,##0.00 ;(#,##0.00)} on decimals, however it is losing the trailing space from the positive values which is keeping the decimal points in line.

Results should be coming out like follows when right aligned:

```
  123.45 |  
 (123.45)|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show some real code on how you are using the `string.Format` Function just showing results without seeing your code defeats the purpose don't you think...?

Comment: Can you post a short and concise code example illustrating your problem? Your format is working fine on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
var numbers = new List<double> {123.45, -123.45, 0, -1, -100000.12345, 100000.12345};

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    var numberString = number.ToString("#,##0.00 ;(#,##0.00)");

    // This is the only way I know how to right-align in console window
    Console.CursorLeft = (Console.BufferWidth - 1) - numberString.Length;

    Console.WriteLine(numberString);
}

// Output:
//                                       123.45
//                                      (123.45)
//                                         0.00
//                                        (1.00)
//                                  (100,000.12)
//                                   100,000.12
```

Comment: Turns out it was the container I was putting the text into that was removing the space on alignment. Your Console trick helped me work that out. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You might find this formatting utility useful

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NET-Framework-4-Formatting-9c4dae8d

Comment: should be a comment not an answer showing links without code examples to go along with a fix or answer really does no good in this case

Comment: Linking to a utility is not helping at all when OP simply asks help with his string.Format format. He's not asking for an offsite resource.

Comment: I didn't have the 50 points for a comment...I'll add a comment next time since now I have 50